# Проверка подключения к Интернету. Почему Exception игонорируется?

Tags: android, email

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает. Отправляю емаил без инета, все равно пишет, что сообщение ушло. Вот код:

```
private class sender_mail_async extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Boolean> {
    ProgressDialog WaitingDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        WaitingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SmsActivity.this, getString(R.string.data_send), getString(R.string.msg_send), true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        WaitingDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(mainContext, getString(R.string.msg_sended), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ((Activity) mainContext).finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            title = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.screen_sendnews_et_title)).getText().toString();
            text = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.screen_sendnews_et_text)).getText().toString();

            from = "*********";
            where = "********";

            MailSenderClass sender = new MailSenderClass("****", "*****");

            sender.sendMail(title, text, from, where);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mainContext, (R.string.error_send_msg), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Так Вы пишите то, что отправлено в пост екзекутье, оно выполнеться в любом случае. Вам надо, если отработал ексепшен, взвести какой-нибудь флаг, чтобы о посте его проверить.

Comment: а как это можно сделать?...

Comment: Как Вам в кетч добавить установку переменной, а в посте её проверять?

Answer (score 1):

Попытка вызова `Toast` внутри `doInBackground()` бессмысленна - в лучшем случае ничего не выйдет, а в худшем получите крэш. `doInBackground` не имеет доступа в юай тред.

По правилам надо корректно завершить `doInBackground` с некоторым кодом ошибки, а в `onPostExecute` обработать ошибку и выдать на-гора то, что вы там себе запланировали.

А вообще совсем по кошерному надо проверить наличие коннекта в `onPreExecute()`, и только если все успешно запускать `doInBackground()`.

И да, использование `Toast` в качестве отладочного лога - это не айс :) На то есть **Logcat**.